# Description of a character in 'War and peace'

Tags: russian-language, leo-tolstoy, war-and-peace

In the book 'War and peace ' , the characters seem to mention the name of a person ' countess Apraksina ' with a tone of respect and concern in chapter 10. This character 'countess Apraksina' is not described in any of the previous chapters.I couldn't understand how she is relevent to the story, please explain (I am reading the translation by Louise and Aylmer Maude).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apraskin is an old [Russian noble family](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B). They are not the only real nobles portrayed in the novel, but I couldn't find exactly whom of the Apraskins Tolstoy had in mind. My guess would be [Ekaterina Vladimirovna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekaterina_Vladimirovna_Apraksina) but I don't have anything reliable to back it up.

Comment: Thank you for answering.So Countess Apraskina is a sick woman of a well known noble family and everybody is concerned about her health.Will this assumption hold for the rest of the stroy?

Comment: She will be mentioned here and there, but she is too minor to have any impact on the story.